# Importing XY coordinates from Excel to MatLab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have imported my XY data (in the same excel worksheet) to matlab with all the X and Y coordinates in separate columns ('FHC'), X is in column b and Y in c. I want to plot these using using k-means.

I got stuck cause I don't like to plot all the coordinates, I like to include the first 10, skip 2 cells and then include the next 10 ect.I tried to specify cells like this (b2:b12,1);(c2:c12,2), it exceeds matrix dimensions?

How can I tell matlab from what cell to what other cell that I want it to include, possibly  tell it to skip some cells in between? My code looks like this at the moment (but now it plots all the X's and all the Y's);

```
X =['FHC',(:,1);(:,2)] %written differently 
opts = statset('Display','final');

[idx,ctrs,sumd,D] = kmeans(X,1,...

 plot(X(idx==1,1),X(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
 hold on
 plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'ko',...
 legend('Cluster 1','Centroid',...
```

Comment: please distill your code  to the bare necessity. It is not clear which of the variables you wrote are cells, maybe you mean elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `X` and `Y` are cells then try this:

```
 %if X is a n by 2 cell array
 hold on
 for ii=1:2:length(X)
     plot(X{ii,1}(1:10),X{ii,2}(1:10),'r.','MarkerSize',12);
 end
 hold off
```

Comment: @ Natan Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work. Don't I need to specify what cells I need out of the sheet at the beginning of the code? After the X = 'FCH' (work sheet with both the X and Y coordinates in separate columns)?

Comment: the current code takes index `idx`, that you used to plot, assuming there is more than one element for `find(idx==1)' and selects the 1st, 3rd, 5th etc...  Again, I asked you to make your code simple to the bare minimum. I don't understand for example, why plotting `plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2)` is relevant, or is it actually the source of your problem.  The first line is completely incomprehensible. I've edited my answer to make the general case...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that cleaned it up and it works fine! Could I harass you with another question? I am new to matlab but I am trying to use it in my master thesis in medicine. I now have all these small clusters, each containing 10 points each and their centroids. I can see that some plots have one or two outliers, that makes my centroid go to far off. Is there a way to exclude these points from my plot? I have read about ODIN and ORC, but I have to say that these codes are greek to me;( Sorry to bother you but I would really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, you should consider to "accept" the answer if it worked fine. Without really seeing what you are talking about, it seems you need some kind of filtering (median and\or conv2 with a kernel etc) before analyzing your code, or a better selection of threshold (maybe local threshold instead of a single value one). I think you should try  to search in StackOverflow for that matter, or start a new question with a sample image and code attached.